# How to pop a string from one stack and push onto another?

Tags: c++

Code snippet:

```
string token;

token = mystack.pop();
```

This gives "operator=" error. It is my understanding this is due to the fact that strings do not have the = operator, and that strcpy() is the proper method.

However, when I use:

```
strcpy(token, mystack.pop());
```

I receive "error: ‘strcpy’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘strcpy’?".

I am quite confused by this. I am new to C++.

My overall goal is to pop, check if it is an operand, then push to the operand stack or the operator stack, if that context helps at all.
Thanks

Comment: "_it is my understanding this is due to the fact that strings do not have the = operator_": That is wrong. `std::string` has a `operator=`. Please be careful to not confuse `std::string` with C-strings (`char*`/`char[]`). These are not the same thing and in C++ you usually only need `std::string`. `strcpy` is for C strings, you won't usually need it in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This gives "operator=" error.

Assuming you are using [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) then its [`pop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) method has a `void` return type, ie it does not return anything, so you can't assign it to your `string`.  You need to instead read from its [`top()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) method before calling `pop()`, eg:

```
string token;

token = mystack.top();
mystack.pop();
```

> It is my understanding this is due to the fact that strings do not have the = operator

Then your understanding is wrong, because they do.

> and that strcpy() is the proper method.

That is true for C-style `char*`/`char[]` strings, but not for C++-style `std::string`s.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the member function [`std::stack::pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) has **return type** of `void`. You can use [`std::stack::top`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) before using `std::stack::pop` as shown below:

```
    std::string token;
    std::stack<std::string> myStack;
    myStack.push("firstString");
    myStack.push("secondString");
    
    token = myStack.top();
     
    myStack.pop();
```

Also, note that `std::string` has overloaded `operator=` and that `strcpy` is used with C-strings which are different from `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

`pop()` only removes the top element from the stack, not return this. You should use

```
token = mystack.top();
mystack.pop();
```